# strcat() causes segfault in c

Tags: c, string, memory-management

The following is a small code snippet from a larger program, it's purpose is to convert 8 int64_t values which are saves in the array value[] of the paramD6P12Array struct into a concatened string of the form:
"+0.000111111111, +0.000222222222, +0.000333333333, ..." (the numbers are just examples).

The result should be saved in the string pointed to by str, and i used another string nextParamValue to convert each individual array value into the right formatting (with the plus and the decimal point at the beginning and the trailing comma and whitepspace) which is then concatened with str.

However when running the program it causes a segmentation fault, it seems like the problem is caused by some line in the for loop (when I comment it out, everything works fine).
I'm quite new to c programming and string manipulation and already read about the string functions strcat() and so on also I used to try malloc() and free() but nothing worked so far. Furthermore when using malloc() and free() the segmentation fault doesn't happen but the programm just seems to suspend, when stepping through with the debugger I noticed the suspension happens with the line where free() is called.

```
#define MAX_CMD_STRSIZE 128;

char str[MAX_CMD_STRSIZE];

PARAM_D6P12_ARRAY* paramD6P12Array = (PARAM_D6P12_ARRAY*)param;
int len;
size_t arraySize = sizeof(paramD6P12Array->value)/sizeof(paramD6P12Array->value[0]);


len = sprintf(str, "%+014"LLD_FMT_STR, paramD6P12Array->value[0]);
int DOT_INDEX = len - 12;
memmove(&str[DOT_INDEX + 1], &str[DOT_INDEX], len + 1 - DOT_INDEX);
str[DOT_INDEX] = '.';
int newLen;
for(int i = 1; i<(int)arraySize; i++){
     char* nextParamValue = (char*)malloc((len+3)*sizeof(char));
     newLen = sprintf(nextParamValue, ", %+014"LLD_FMT_STR, paramD6P12Array->value[i]);
     DOT_INDEX = newLen - (12+2);
     memmove(&nextParamValue[DOT_INDEX + 1 + 2], &nextParamValue[DOT_INDEX+2], len + 1 - DOT_INDEX);
     nextParamValue[DOT_INDEX+2] = '.';
     //memmove(&str[len+1], nextParamValue, newLen+1);
     strcat(&str[len], nextParamValue);
     len += newLen;
     }
     free(nextParamValue);
}
```

Comment: Try: `strcat(&str[len], nextParamValue);` --> `strcat(str, nextParamValue);`

Comment: This is an incomplete example that does not reproduce the problem.  One of the most important things to see is the declaration of `str`.  Is it an array?  A pointer?  How large is it?

Comment: I think, the `+2` is logically wrong or at least redundant but not related to your problem. If you allocate and free memory for more numbers in the loop, you might think about using an array on the stack.

Comment: @TomKarzes oh sorry actually the function containing the conversion is called with the variable command for parameter str, i edited the code.

Comment: @kaylum I tried it but the segfault still occurs. I missed that strcat is searching for the \0 terminating str, so there is no ned to call it with the adress of the end of str.

Comment: @Lukas does it work now?

Comment: @Gerhardh the +2 is because all the parameters except the first one include the leading ", " so 2 additional characters before the decimal point at DOT_INDEX in the string

Comment: @Jabberwocky no the segfault still occurs.

Comment: I know but you count from the right side where the +2 do not matter. You only need to add the +2 for every step to compensate for that.

Comment: How many numbers do you add to the string? What is `param`?

Comment: You're overwriting memory somewhere. Try to make your buffers much larger and if the problem goes away you know where to look. Also `#define MAX_CMD_STRSIZE 128;` -> `#define MAX_CMD_STRSIZE 128`, the `;` is wrong.

Comment: @Gerhardh Oh yeah now i see thank you, so actually i don't need the +2 when updating DOT_INDEX but the +2 in the call of memmove are necessary as i am counting from the left.

Comment: No, if you remove +2 everywhere, `DOT_INDEX` will already point to the right place because then you don't subtract +2 too much from it in first place. Each occurance of +2 is just compensation for subtracting too much in the beginning.

Comment: @Gerhardh param is a struct that among other things contains the array int64_t value[8] that contains the 8 values which i like to convert into the mentioned format and parse into str, (param is the struct before typecasted into the right type) inside the function i work with its casted version paramD6P12Array

Comment: Did you check that `arraysize` is 8?

Comment: @Gerhardh I got your point with the DOT_INDEX now, yes ```arraysize``` is 8 i checked that

Comment: @Jabberwocky i already increased the buffer to 256, the ; isn't there in the actual program i somehow inserted it only in the code posted here

Comment: I finally got the problem: I assigned to less space to nextParamValue with malloc(), the problem is i used to old length of str which is one less then the length after str has the decimal point inserted, so when calling free(nextParamValue) there is some problem happening. maybe because the string is no longer 0-terminated? It works fine with ```char* nextParamValue = (char*)malloc((strlen(str)+1+2)*sizeof(char));``` +1 for the 0-termination and +2 because each value except the first one feature 2 additional characters namely ", " at the beginning

Comment: You know that `strlen(str)` will be called in each iteration of the loop and will increase with each number that is added to `str`, do you? You could simply do `len++;`once before the loop. Or just define maximum length of each number as a macro you use in `malloc` or even drop that dynamic memory allocation completely.

Comment: strlen(str) isn't called inside the loop only once before it, but I dropped the dynamic memory allocation now as you suggested